# ERROR: polling failed in /home/jenkins/test on sk-node(83) java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks, cloning

I configured a Jenkins pipeline to clone my repository. When I manually click on the build now button it works fine but when I try to make a new commit in my GitHub repository and that webhook payload also comes to Jenkins, the pipeline is poked but the pipeline is not triggered . I am not getting the the line "scm changes detected in pipeline. Triggering #buildNumber" in my system log. I enabled the "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" in my pipeline configuration.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'my-node' }
    stages {
        stage('Clone repository') {
            environment {
                GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
               // SMTP_CREDENTIALS = credentials('SESSMTP')
            }
            steps {
               dir('/home/jenkins/test4/') {
                    git branch: 'master',credentialsId: 'github-cred', url: 'https://github.com/example/example.git'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the pipeline I am using and all my credentials are correct. And i am using a private repo with multiple branches.

I want to know why SCM changes are not detecting in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got this kind of error when the webhook payload came to Jenkins. The reason behind this error is whenever a new commit is made in your GitHub repository the webhook payload comes to the Jenkins master and in the Jenkins master the pipeline is validated according to the pipeline code. This means the commit that is made on the branch and the branch that we specified in the pipeline code is the same or not then only the Jenkins master will execute the pipeline with the user credentials that we specified in the node(The SCM changes are detected and the corresponding pipeline will be triggered). The mistake that I made was "GIT is not installed in my Jenkins master why the pipeline is not validated then I installed the git in the Jenkins master and executed a command called "which git" This gave me the git path in the Jenkins master and I paste this path under **Manage Jenkins** --> **Tools** --> **Git installations** --> **Path to git executable**

Now the Jenkins detected the changes and the pipeline is triggered